# Random forest - short text classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I have read this [article](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2013/ShiraniMehr-SMSSpamDetectionUsingMachineLearningApproach.pdf) which compares various machine learning algorithms on SMS spam detection. I have been able to reproduce results for Naive Bayes and now i would like to try Random Forest as well.

With Naive Bayes, it's straightforward. The bag-of-words model is used and missing probabilities are handled with Laplace smoothing. Only words present in an SMS are tested against SPAM|HAM classes. However, i am not sure how to handle the input with random forest.

Suppose i have following setup:

- 5000 distinct words in training set, after stemming and removal of stop words
- text to classify is short, e.g. 10 words in average
- CART used as a tree model
- random forest selects subset of features, say 2*sqrt(5000) = 141 words for each split
- word frequency is used as feature value(could be also TF-IDF)

So my questions are:

1. *Generally speaking, regardless of article, can random forest be used effectively for short text classification when the feature space is large ?* *It seems to me that there may be a lot of weak classifiers due to large feature space and only handful of features present in data to classify.*
2. *How to handle unseen words with random forest(not present in training set)? Should they be simply stripped from input or some technique similar to Laplace smoothing should be used* ?
3. *If somebody perhaps read this short article, maybe could explain how author represented features for random forest* ?

Comment: Its worth mentining: rf does not sample predictors for each tree, they are sampled for each split.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, in a machine learning approach, it is **recommended to test several models** regardless of their theoretical performance, because their accuracy is dependent of the training dataset. True enough, a couple of algorithms are *generally* preferred for text classification (SVM, Naive Bayes, multinomial regressions) for various reasons such as linear separation or curse of dimensionality (see [this paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_98a.pdf)). However, nothing prevents you from trying a random forest and examine its performance.

Now to answer your questions.

> *Generally speaking, regardless of article, can random forest be used effectively for short text classification when the feature space is large ? It seems to me that there may be a lot of weak classifiers due to large feature space and only handful of features present in data to classify.*

Given the nature of **random forests** (a ***bagging decision tree***), it is true that you may come up with a rather weak classifier, especially if only a couple of features are truly significant to determine the outcome. A ***boosting decision tree*** may be preferred (such as adaboost or gradient boosting) to weight relevant predictors.

However, keep in mind that in the case of text classification, a preprocessing phase is required to get either your TF or TF-IDF matrix, through which you have **already made a selection of pertinent features**. Potentially, all features are relevant in this matrix, so the random forest may be performant when you predict your outcome.

> How to handle unseen words with random forest(not present in training set)? Should they be simply stripped from input or some technique similar to Laplace smoothing should be used ?

Since you are using word frequency as a feature, you have already defined the grid over which you will be evaluating the outcome of your message. **Unseen words will be filtered and stripped** in your algorithm because you will be evaluating if the words in your test set are present/absent in your TF matrix.

> If somebody perhaps read this short article, maybe could explain how author represented features for random forest ?

The author uses `scikit-learn` library from `python`. I conclude that the dataset was most likely a numerical dataframe (categorical values are always converted into logical dummy booleans in `python`). From my understanding, the author used the following features :

- Filtered words, based on their frequency ($>5$ and $<500$), and more specifically, if they are absent/present in the message.
- Message length (number of characters in message), later transformed into five categorical booleans (message length $\le 40$, $\le 60$, ...)
- Occurrences of character \$
- Number of numeric strings
- Presence/absence of non-alphabetic characters